# Mongodb $pull with async/await not working properly

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have the following UserSchema

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    // Irrelevant properties
    likedPrograms: [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Program'}], 
});
```

I am trying to remove a program from this array with this query

```
const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$pull: {likedPrograms: {_id: programToRemove._id}}}, {new: true});
```

However, this line of code is executing without removing the element from the array. Is it a problem with async/await? If I try to do it with callbacks it works, however, I don't like to use callbacks in my code as I don't want to run into callback hell.Any ideas on why this is not working?

Comment: It should be `{$pull: {likedPrograms: programToRemove._id}}` Or please show `programToRemove` object

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anthony. Refering to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/ i can write `{ $pull: { <field1>: <value|condition>, <field2>: <value|condition>, ... } }`, being `{_id: programToRemove._id}` a condition why this is not working properly? and why does your version works?

Comment: Have a look at your schema you have not taken any field it is simple array of objectIds not with array of object with key value pair. It would have worked if you had taken like so `likedPrograms: [{_id: { type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Program' }, }], `

Comment: Well, that explains a lot :/ I don't know how to mark your comment as the answer tot his question but you surely deserve this one, my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with async await or callbacks. If you can take a look at your schema you have not taken any field inside the `likedPrograms`,  it is just simple array of `ObjectIds` not with array of object with key value pair.

It would have worked if you had taken like so

```
likedPrograms: [{ _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Program' }}]
```